# Why indexing a Theano tensor variable with a list of `slice` objects is invalid?

Tags: python, theano

In an [exercise](https://github.com/goodfeli/theano_exercises/blob/master/01_basics/03_advanced_expressions/02_nd_indexing.py) of Dr. Goodfellow's Theano tutorial, it's ok to slice `x` with tuple `(slice(w,-w), )*x.ndim`, but Theano will raise exception for `[slice(w,-w)]*x.ndim` .

Exception info:

> theano.tensor.var.AsTensorError: ('Cannot convert [slice(, Elemwise{neg,no_inplace}.0, None), slice(, Elemwise{neg,no_inplace}.0, None), slice(, Elemwise{neg,no_inplace}.0, None)] to TensorType', )

Why doesn't it work with `list`? BTW, slicing a tensor variable with an integer list is ok.
I've red the [document](https://theano.readthedocs.org/en/latest/library/tensor/basic.html#indexing), but didn't find the reason.

Comment: Wild guess: at some point in the slicing code, there is a type check.  At a minimum, it would need to check whether `index is Ellipsis`, but it might also want to check for integers and other such things.  It probably does `isinstance(index, tuple)`, and when that fails, it blows up.

Comment: I've posted a message to theano-users about this. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/theano-users/nTRfigJD19w

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in Theano. It has been fixed by Frédéric Bastien via https://github.com/Theano/Theano/pull/2992

More here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/theano-users/nTRfigJD19w